# What is the name/how it works this MVC characteristic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have used this characteristic of MVC, where you have a control in a view, lets say a checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBox("isNewlyEnrolled", true)
```

and in the controller you declare a parameter with the same name:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchExpressionTester(string isNewlyEnrolled, SearchExpressionModel SearchExpression)
```

Then you can use the value of the checkbox in the controller.

Is this process of the controller receiving the string value that I don't fully understand. I know there's no need to add a new parameter to the model.

I can't find information about how this Works in any MVC book, article and so on. What is the name of this technique for passing parameters to the controler?

Comment: It's called Model Binding

Comment: [The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using [HTML Helpers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/html-helpers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/), that's all. You could also do `<input type="checkbox" name="isNewlyEnrolled" checked="checked">` and the result would be the same.

Basically, you are using built-in functions to generate HTML elements.

List of most used HTML helpers:

- Html.Beginform
- Html.Label
- Html.TextBox
- Html.TextArea
- Html.Password
- Html.DropDownList
- Html.CheckBox
- Html.RadioButton
- Html.Hidden

#### Html.Beginform

Usage:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

Produces:

```
<form action="..." action="post">
```

#### Html.Label

Usage:

```
@Html.Label("Name")
```

Produces:

```
<label for="Name">
    Name
</lable>
```

#### Html.TextBox

Usage:

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", null, null)
```

Produces:

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
```

#### Html.TextArea

Usage:

```
@Html.TextArea("Description", null, null)
```

Produces:

```
<textarea id="Description" name="Description" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

#### Html.Password

Usage:

```
@Html.Password("Password")
```

Produces:

```
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="" />
```

#### Html.DropDownList

Usage:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), "Select Gender", null)
```

Produces:

```
<select id="StudentGender" name="StudentGender">
    <option>Select Gender</option> 
    <option>Male</option> 
    <option>Female</option> 
</select>
```

#### Html.RadioButton

Usage:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male")
```

Produces:

```
<input checked="checked" id="Gender" name="Gender" type="radio" value="Male" />
```

#### Html.Hidden

Usage:

```
@Html.Hidden("StudentId")
```

Produces:

```
<input id="StudentId" name="StudentId" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

---

Go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) to learn more are about model binding in ASP.NET.

Comment: This is not at all the question being asked. It's not about the Html helpers, it's about the binding of the form elements to the action's parameters

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  That also ;)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't see any reason to believe the OP doesn't understand what the HTML helpers are

Comment: Since he/she never mentioned HTML helpers in his/her question I assumed he/she doesn't know what the technique is called. So, go ahead and write an answer regarding model binding. :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see this as a two part question, the helper and model binding i.e. "this characteristic of MVC" meaning HTML Helper in this context and the model binding part so both.  For the OP: Lots of results on the model binding use this in for favorite search engine: "model binding mvc c# site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: It is not specific to this question but there is also `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.isNewlyEnrolled, new { @checked = "checked" })`

Comment: Yes, I'm not talking about the HTML Helpers. As far as I know the view sends a Dictionary or Collection with pairs of control_name/value. I have seen examples, and I know that this Works, but I want to learn more about this topic, and can't find more info.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the question!